# How to send vector of string to MATLAB compiled DLLs, using mwArray?

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Page at [mwArray class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/mwarray.html) describes about constructor to create a mwArray cell of array of string as:
`mwArray(mwSize num_strings, const char** str)`. I have a vector of string which has been dynamically populated. I have converted `vector<string>` to `char**` and trying to make mwArray with this data. However, the constructor signature has `const char**`, so it is failing to convert `char**` to `const char**`

How else a vector of string can be set to a mwArray cell and sent to MATLAB DLLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert vector to const char **. Here is one such functions.

```
const char** convert(vector< string > &v)
{
    int kk;

    const char** ppChar = new const char *[v.size()];

    for (kk = 0; kk < v.size(); kk++)
    {
        ppChar[kk] = const_cast< char* >(v[kk].c_str());
    }

    return ppChar;
 }
```

to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k;

    vector< string > v;

    v.push_back("This is string");
    v.push_back("Another string a bit longer");
    v.push_back("my string");

    const char** AA = convert(v);

    for (k = 0; k < v.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << AA[k] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```